# chain homotopy equivalences are quasi-isomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Suppose that $f:C_\bullet\to D_\bullet,g:D_\bullet\to C_\bullet$ form a homotopy equivalence.
Then we have $\delta:C_\bullet\to C_{\bullet+1},\epsilon:D_\bullet\to D_{\bullet+1}$ with
$g\circ f -\operatorname{id}_{C_\bullet}=\partial\circ\delta+\delta\circ\partial$
$f\circ g -\operatorname{id}_{D_\bullet}=\partial\circ\epsilon+\epsilon\circ\partial$
It's pretty easy to show that $f_n(\ker\partial^C_n)\leq\ker\partial^D_n,g_n(\ker\partial^D_n)\leq\ker\partial^C_n$, but I don't know how to get an isomorphism between the kernels - let alone the images.

Comment: You won’t get an isomorphism between the kernels (or the images), just in homology. To do this, just show that any two homotopic maps induce the same morphism in homology.

Comment: What do you mean by a quasi-isomorphism?

Comment: This would be in pretty much any Algebraic Topology textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more generally (and as @Aphelli said): if $f$ and $f'$ are chain homotopic maps $C_\bullet \to D_\bullet$ — that is, if there is a map $H: C_\bullet \to D_{\bullet + 1}$ such that $f - f' = \partial H + H \partial$ — then $f$ and $f'$ induce the same map on homology. The reason: if $z$ is a cycle in $C$, then $f(z) - f'(z) = \partial H(z) + H \partial (z) = \partial H(z)$: this says that $f(z) - f'(z)$ is a boundary and hence $f(z)$ is homologous to $f'(z)$.

So in the case you're asking about, $(g \circ f)_* = g_* \circ f_*$ is the identity map (using stars to denote the induced maps on homology), and similarly for $(f \circ g)_* = f_* \circ g_*$, which means that $f_*$ and $g_*$ are inverses to each other, and hence isomorphisms.